# Uniqueness of a linear map for which $Tv_{k} = w_{k}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am reading Sheldon Axler's masterpiece *Linear Algebra Done Right* (Fourth Edition).  If you thought you knew linear algebra, read this - you'll learn more in the first 50 pages than the entirety of a typical 300+ level course.

Anyways, I am having a bit of trouble following one of his results.  He states and proves the following.

**3.4 linear map lemma**

Suppose $v_{1}, \ldots, v_{n}$ is a basis of $V$ and $w_{1}, \ldots, w_{n} \in W$.  Then there exists a unique linear map $T: V \rightarrow W$ such that $Tv_{k} = w_{k}$ for each $k = 1, 2, \ldots, n$.

*Proof*

In the interest of brevity, I will skip the first part of the proof where he shows that the function

$$T(c_{1}v_{1} + \ldots + c_{n}v_{n}) = c_{1}w_{1} + c_{2}w_{2} + \cdots + c_{n}w_{n}$$

is indeed a linear map from $V$ to $W$ for which $Tv_{k} = w_{k}$ for each $k = 1, \ldots, n$.

**The next part is what confuses me.**

To prove uniqueness, now suppose that $T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$ and that $Tv_{k} = w_{k}$ for each $k = 1, \ldots, n$.  Let $c_{1}, \ldots, c_{n} \in \mathbf{F}$ (where $\mathbf{F}$ is a field, usually $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$).  Then the homogeneity of $T$ implies that $T(c_{k}v_{k}) = c_{k}w_{k}$ for each $k = 1, \ldots, n$.  The additivity of $T$ now implies that

$$T(c_{1}v_{1} + \ldots + c_{n}v_{n}) = c_{1}w_{1} + \cdots + c_{n}w_{n}$$

Thus $T$ is uniquely determined on span$(v_{1}, \ldots, v_{n})$ by the equation above.  Because $v_{1}, \ldots, v_{n}$ is a basis of $V$, this implies that $T$ is uniquely determined on $V$, as desired.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you had another $T_0$ for which $T_0v_k=w_k$, then $T$ and $T_0$ will send a base, the v's, to the same base, the w's. that means that every element of V will have identical image through $T$ and $T_0$

Comment: When this type of argument leaves me less than enlightened, I modify it as follows: "Let $S,T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$" and then make $S$ satisfy whatever we require of $T$, and then computing $S - T$.  Here, we get to $T(c_1v_1 + \cdots + c_nv_n) = \dots = S(c_1v_1 + \cdots + c_nv_n)$, so $S$ and $T$ are equal on the span of the $v_i$, and are therefore equal on $V$.

Comment: @temp minor change in "the same base, the w's". Get rid of the insinuation that the w's have to be a base too.

Comment: youu are right, I meant "to the same subspace of W, whose base are the w's" and I write it poorly

Answer (score 3):

The point is that because $\{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n \}$ is a basis, there's only one way to express any element of $V$ as a linear combination of the $v_i$ (that follows from linear independence), and each element of $V$ can be expressed as such a linear combination (that follows because the $v_i$ span $V$).

So for any element $v \in V$, express $v= \sum c_iv_i$.  We now know that $Tv=\sum c_i w_i$, and we can come up with such a combination for all $v \in V$.

Answer (score 1):

@Robert Shore has already answered.

Just **a hint**: try to construct examples. It will get easier and easier with practice.

Here, I propose the following example : $$V=W=\mathbb R^2, v_1=w_1(1,0), v_2=(0,1), w_2=(0,0)$$

There exists a unique linear map $T$ such that $T(v_1)=w_1$ and $T(v_2)=w_2$:$$T:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$$ $$v=(x,y)=xv_1+yv_2\mapsto (x,0)=xw_1$$
[image]
This is the projection on $\mathbb Rv_1$ parallel to $\mathbb Rv_2$